# How to cast member variable pointer to generic type in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, member-pointers

I have code similar to this in my application:

```
class A
{
  public: int b;
}

class C
{
  public: int d;
}

void DoThings (void *arg1, MYSTERYTYPE arg2);

A obj_a;
C obj_c;

DoThings(&obj_a, &A::b);
DoThings(&obj_c, &C::d);
```

The question is - What should MYSTERYTYPE be? neither void* nor int work, despite the value &A::b being printed just fine if you output it through a printf.

Clarifications: Yes, &A::b is defined under C++. Yes, I am trying to get the offset to a class member. Yes, I am being tricky.

Edit: Oh I can use offsetof(). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting.  I took down my answer, j_random_hacker gets creds.

Comment: Edited so DoThings looks like it could do something that makes sense since you guys are so keen on things making sense.

Comment: zarawesome, you can't always use offsetof. if you have a non-POD, it's not possible (it's nonpod already if you got a user defined constructor, or private datamembers). member pointers are highly recommended

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks, funny though, I thought I was way off in lala land...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a data member pointer to two unrelated classes. Well, you can't find a common type that can hold both pointers. It will only work if the function parameter is a data member pointer to a member of the derived, because it's guaranteed to contain the member too, if a base contains it:

```
struct a { int c; }; struct b : a { }; int main() { int b::*d = &a::c; }
```

---

**Update**: I think i should write why the above converts from `a::*` to `b::*` implicitly. After all, we usually have `b*` to `a*` ! Consider:

```
struct a { };
struct b : a { int c; };
struct e : a { };
int main() { int a::*d = &b::c; e e_; (e_.*d) = 10; /* oops! */ }
```

If the above would be valid, you would really much screw up. The above is *not* valid, because conversion from `b::*` to `a::*` is not implicit. As you see, we assigned a pointer to b::c, and then we could dereference it using a class that doesn't contain it at all! (`e`). The compiler enforces this order:

```
int main() { int b::*d = &b::c; e e_; (e_.*d) = 10; /* bug! */ }
```

It *fails* to compile now, because `e` is not derived from `b`, the class the member pointer pointer belongs to. Good! The following, however, is very valid and compiles, of course (changed classes `a` and `b`):

```
struct a { int c; };
struct b : a { };
struct e : a { };
int main() { int e::*d = &a::c; e e_; (e_.*d) = 10; /* works! */ }
```

---

To make it work for your case, you have to make your function a template:

```
template<typename Class>
void DoThings (int Class::*arg) { /* do something with arg... */ }
```

Now, the compiler will auto-deduce the right class that the given member pointer belongs too. You will have to pass the instance alongside of the member pointer to actually make use of it:

```
template<typename Class>
void DoThings (Class & t, int Class::*arg) { 
    /* do something with arg... */ 
    (t.*arg) = 10;
}
```

If you just want to set some member you already know at the time you write DoThings, the following suffices:

```
template<typename Class>
void DoThings (Class & t) {  
    t.c = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you simply trying to call a function with the address of an integer that happens to live inside an `A` or a `C` object?  In that case, Jeff McGlynn's answer is the way to go.

Otherwise, if you really are trying to do something tricky requiring C++'s weird pointer-to-member facility (and you almost certainly aren't):

Since classes `A` and `C` are unrelated, you will need a template function to handle both:

```
template <typename T>
void DoThings(int T::*x);
```

If `C` was actually derived from `A`, the following would work:

```
void DoThings(int A::*x);
```

Comment: Wow, I just saw this after I posted my edit.  How'd we post the same thing? :-)

Comment: random_hacker, it's the other way around. for member pointers, the relationship is reversed: int C::*x would be the common type of the parameter

Comment: @litb: If C is derived from A, and you want to be able to call DoThings() with either a type A object or a type C object, operating on the element b in either case, the parameter will need to be of type "int A::*", right?  If you used "int C::*", you couldn't pass objects of type A.

Comment: j_random_hacker, no. You don't have a A or B object/pointer. you have a A/B member pointer. Say A has "int d;", B has "float c". and you accept "float A::*". and you pass "&B::c", it would work, even though A has no member A::c !.

Comment: So, making it clear, your function would look like: void fun(base * b, int derived::*d);

Comment: Hmm, that seems surprising...  Suggests you must always use pointer-to-member parameters of the most-derived type, meaning you could only ever pass objects of that or an ancestral type, never sibling types.  Thanks, at some point I will read up on this properly...

Comment: ah wait. it has to be void fun(derived* b, int derived::*d); sorry. because you can't do (b->*d) because it doesn't know whether d points to a member of base. but the impossible of the implicit conversion from T d::* to T b::* stands of course

Comment: so D* converts to B* and T B::* converts to T D::* . and if you want to call the member function pointer, you have to use at least a D* . only that makes sure that you don't violate type system rules

Comment: yeah that's quite confusing :D

Answer (score 0):

&A::b and &C::d are nonsensical, there is no associated address. Are you trying to get the offset of the member?

Are you sure you don't want something like the following?

```
DoSomething(&obj_a,&obj_a.b);
```

Comment: sqlrob: "&A::b" is valid C++ code, with the effect of returning a pointer-to-data-member type, of type "int (A::*)".

Comment: I'm more used to pointer to member functions, not data.  Having a pointer to member data just doesn't seem useful, especially if it has to be a pointer to a particular data member, as the syntax in the example implies.

Answer (score 0):

If you use templates as j_random_hacker suggests, and the compiler knows the type of each class at the point where you call the function, the literal answer to your question is "`template <typename CLASS> void DoThings (CLASS * object, int CLASS::*MEMBER)`".

Here's how it would fit into your example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public: 
    int b;
};

class C {
public: 
    int d;
};

template <typename CLASS>
void DoThings (CLASS * object, int CLASS::*MEMBER)
{
    std::cout << object->*MEMBER << std::endl;
}

A obj_a = { 2 };
C obj_c = { 4 };

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    DoThings(&obj_a, &A::b);
    DoThings(&obj_c, &C::d);
    return 0;
}
```